# PHP: Problems opening some XML Files

Tags: php, xml

I am having a headache trying to parse XML files.

Previously, my script to open and parse XML files has worked flawlessly. However, today I noticed it was not working correctly so I took a look.

My XML files are uniquely formatted. Unfortunately I cannot show an example of those. When I looked into the issue though, I realized they were being improperly read by PHP. Instead of reading the entire file into a string, it strips the XML tags and only takes in the values between those tags. I have no idea why it is doing this.

Not much example code:

```
echo file_get_contents(URL_TO_FILE);
```

Comment: `echo htmlspecialchars(file_get_contents(URL_TO_FILE));` (or stop looking at non-HTML data in a HTML client).

Comment: This may sound silly, but are you viewing the page as presented in the browser or **viewing the page source** when you say " Instead of reading the entire file into a string, it strips the XML tags and only takes in the values between those tags"?

Comment: *"Unfortunately I cannot show an example of those."* Then anonymize your data.

Comment: jedwards - You were dead on. Sorry for the sillyness :(

Comment: DO NOT use the general file opening function to open an XML file, it's not as specialized as the XML specific one, especially on large files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?php
$xml=simplexml_load_file("note.xml");
print_r($xml);
?>
```

Sounds like you are viewing the xml in an html reader (browser). This will ignore the tags of course. Be sure you are viewing the source.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. Every other time I opened an XML file and echoed the results, it parsed them into an RSS-style page. This time it didn't - but I did not even think to simply check the source. Sorry for the sillyness on my part. At least I found out a better way to open XML files in the process though